# private member function access

Tags: java, private, member-functions

I am new to java... If I am missing something, please advise me.

I try to access the private method like below:

```
public class PublicClassPrivateMethodAndVariableAccess
{
    private int a=23;

    private void show()
    {
        System.out.println("a = "+a);
    }

    public static void main(String... arg)
    {
        PublicClassPrivateMethodAndVariableAccess pr = new PublicClassPrivateMethodAndVariableAccess();
        System.out.println("using method showing  pr.show() ");
        pr.show();
        System.out.println("pr.a = "+pr.a);
    }
}
```

This will show output as:

```
using method showing  pr.show()

a = 23

pr.a = 23
```

But when I’m using a similar code with a different way to access the private method...:

```
class Testclass
{
    private int a=23;

    private void show()
    {
        System.out.println("a = "+a);
    }   
}

public class NoModifierClassPrivateMethodAndVariableAccess
{
    public static void main(String... arg)
    {
        Testclass pr = new Testclass();
        System.out.println("using method showing  pr.show() ");
        pr.show();
        System.out.println("pr.a = "+pr.a);
    }
}
```

... it shows error as below:

```
NoModifierClassPrivateMethodAndVariableAccess.java:19: error: show() has private
 access in Testclass
                pr.show();
                  ^
NoModifierClassPrivateMethodAndVariableAccess.java:20: error: a has private access in Testclass
                System.out.println("pr.a = "+pr.a);
                                               ^
2 errors
```

I am asking why this second code is failing to access the private method?

Comment: A `private` method is only visible in the class that contains it. Example 1: Everything is in `PublicClassPrivateMethodAndVariableAccess` and thus `show()` is visible. In Example 2: You put the method in another class, so the method isn't visible. Make it `public`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-difference-between-package-private-public-protected-and-private?rq=1

Comment: _"Make it `public`"_  Or keep it private and add a getter and/or setter.

Comment: thanks i understand..one more in my code, is Testclass is public or private class?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a getter for your private item.

You cannot directly access a private item which is exactly what you are trying to do when you enter

```
System.out.println("pr.a = "+pr.a);
```

instead you should use a getter such as

```
   public int getA(){
       return a;
}
```

so your new display should be something like

```
System.out.println("pr.a = "+pr.getA());
```

Answer (score 0):

A private field `a` can **only** be accessed by its owning class `A_Class` itself. For example:

```
public class A_Class {
    private int a = 3;
    private void show() {
        System.out.println(a); // output is 3
    }
}
```

Here we are:

- inside `A_Class`
- accessing private field `a`

That is what you are doing in your first code and that works fine.

---

But, in your second code you are in class `B_Class` trying to access the private field `a` that is owned by class `A_Class` and that is not possible. For example:

```
public class A_Class {
    private a = 3;
}

public class B_Class {
    void show() {
        private A_Class aclass = new A_Class();
        System.out.println(aclass.a); // error! a has private access
    }
}
```

Here we are:

- inside `B_Class`
- creating an object of class `A_Class`
- trying to access the field `a`, that has private access only to class `A_Class` - *this fails!*

[Here](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/05/all-about-java-modifier-keywords/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-difference-between-package-private-public-protected-and-private?rq=1) you can find some more explanation to java modifiers.

Comment: i ask u one more thing ...in my code, is Testclass is public or private?

Comment: `Testclass` is neither *private* nor *public*. `Testclass` has no modifier and thus it is *package*-visible. That means, only the classes that are in a package together with `Testclass` can access (see) `Testclass`. Maybe this will also help you: https://www.decodejava.com/java-class-access-modifiers.htm

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle docs:

```
+-------------+-------+---------+----------+-------+
|  Modifier   | Class | Package | Subclass | World |
+-------------+-------+---------+----------+-------+
| public      | Y     | Y       | Y        | Y     |
| protected   | Y     | Y       | Y        | N     |
| no modifier | Y     | Y       | N        | N     |
| private     | Y     | N       | N        | N     |
+-------------+-------+---------+----------+-------+
```

In the first case you where calling the `show` method from same class which is possible as per doc.

In second case your calling a private method from different class which will cause compiler error.

If you really want to access a private method from different class , then you want to look into [Reflections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) in Java.

Example:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

class Testclass
{
    private int a=23;

    private void show()
    {
        System.out.println("a = "+a);
    }   
}

public class NoModifierClassPrivateMethodAndVariableAccess
{
    public static void main(String... arg) throws Exception
    {
        Class<?> clazz = Testclass.class;
        Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("show");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println(method.invoke(Testclass.class.newInstance()));

    }
}
```